# Julia: Why is the memory blowing up inside this loop?

Tags: julia

I have some multi-threaded code in which each thread calls a function `f(df::DataFrame)` which reads a column of that DataFrame and finds the indices where the column is greater than 0:

```
function f(df::DataFrame)
    X = df[:time]
    return findall(x->x>0, X)
end
```

Inside the main thread I read in an R *.rds file which Julia converts to a DataFrame which I'm passing to `f()` as follows:

```
rds = "blabla.rds"
objs = load(rds);

params = collect(0.5:0.005:0.7)

for i in 1:length(objs)
    cols = [string(name) for name in names(objs.data[i]) if occursin("bla",string(name))]
    hypers = [(a,b) for a in cols, b in params] # length ~2000
    Threads.@threads for hi in 1:length(hypers) # MEMORY BLOWS UP HERE
        df = f(objs.data[i])
    end
end
```

Each `df` that is passed to `f()` is roughly 0.7GB. Analysing the memory usage when the multi-threaded loop is run, the memory usage goes up to ~30GB. There are 25 threads and ~2000 calls to `f()`. Any idea why the memory is exploding?

NOTE: The problem seems to be ameliorated by calling GC.gc() inside the loop every so often, which seems like a botch...
NOTE also: This happens whether or not I use a regular or multi-threaded loop.

EDIT:
Profiling the code as follows:

```
function foo(objs)
    for i in 1:length(objs)
        df = objs.data[i]
        Threads.@threads for hi in 1:2000
            tmp = f(df)
        end
    end
end

@benchmark(foo($objs))
```

gives

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  32.93 GiB
  allocs estimate:  48820
  --------------
  minimum time:     2.577 s (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.614 s (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        2.614 s (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     2.651 s (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          2
  evals/sample:     1
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems like all the hype surrounding Julia is unfounded. You can't run it as a script because of slow startup times, and you have to do your own garbage collection after each loop iteration, which really slows things down. Seems like it's not about to replace python anytime soon.

Comment: This seems like a pretty weird remark. It is certainly not true that you generally need to run your own garbage collection. I have _never_ experienced that. Julia's threading model is still in development, btw.

Comment: This happens whether or not i use a multi-threaded or regular loop.

Comment: Are you benchmarking/profiling this in the global scope? Can you try wrapping it in a function and profiling that?

Comment: Also, re-write this call: `findall(X .> 0)` to `findall(x->x>0, X)`. The former makes _a lot_ of unnecessary allocations.

Comment: Furthermore: It's pretty unclear what the code is supposed to do. `df` is overwritten on every iteration, which is odd. `cols` and `hypers` don't seem to do anything, except have their lengths measured, so you don't really need to construct them in the first place, instead just count the relevant number of `name`s. Any chance of making a MWE?

Comment: This is just an example. The whole code is too long to put here.

Comment: Sure, but it would be good if you can then simplify the code as much as possible, so that it doesn't do things that confuse the issue and distracts from the main point.

Comment: @DNF why findall(X .> 0) is more efficient than findall(x->x>0, X)?

Comment: It's not, normally. It's _less_ efficient. `find(X.>0)` creates a temporary array and then searches inside it, passing over memory twice. `find(x->x>0, X)` just directly passes over `X` once, makes comparisons and collects the indices.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Threads.@threads starts a thread per iteration element and they are all running at once.  You will have slow speeds on each thread and high memory consumption.

It doesn't execute quickly on one thread at a time.  For that you need something else.